# Setting PATH on Mac so that it persists between sessions

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, environment-variables

I've written a shell script on my Mac that runs fine from the folder. Trying to make it globally executable I've used the following script:

`export PATH="$PATH:~/scripts"`

Subsequently, I can run the command `blaster` from any folder. However, if I close my terminal window, it seems that the PATH gets lost and I have to run the original command again. Any idea why that `export PATH` needs to be re-established?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *No* they won't

Because your current `export` is retained in the current shell you were running the scripts from. As soon as the shell is terminated, the exported variables loose their scope. Add a line

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts' >> ~/.bashrc
```

To make the changes permanent, add the line in either of `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` or `.profile` depending upon your login shell. These files are read and sourced ( executed in the current shell) before your prompt appears, and from subsequent point you can call your script directly

Comment: The tilde- `~` does not expand to the users home folder when it is  enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @fd0: better now! Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This should permanently include all shell scripts in that directory?

Comment: @JesseJamesRichard : Yes it will!

Comment: Is there a way to create a script which updates the path for the current terminal session yet not in a permanent manner as writing it into `.bashrc`? Or maybe open a new terminal from a script with the updated path?

Comment: echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$NEW' will keep it for the current terminal session and all it's child sessions.